Getting error in spring while saving entity
I am getting error while saving an User entity in spring using jpa/hibernate. Below is my User entity class
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class User extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @Email
    String email;

    @Column(name = "user_type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    UserType userType;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    Address address;

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    Boolean active = false;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{10}$", message = "Phone number must be exactly 10 digits")
    String phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    CompanyInformation companyInformation;

    @Column(name = "hashed_password", nullable = false)
    String hashedPassword;

    @Column(name = "kyc_done")
    Boolean kycDone = false;
}

and below are my Address and CompanyInformation entities
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Address extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @ToString.Exclude
    User user;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    String addressName;

    @Column(name = "address1", nullable = false)
    String address1;

    @Column(name = "address2", nullable = false)
    String address2;

    @Column(name = "zipCode", nullable = false)
    String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Country country;

    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    State state;

    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;
}


    @Entity
@Table(name = "company_info")
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class CompanyInformation extends Auditable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    User user;

    @Column(name = "company_name", nullable = false)
    String companyName;

    @Column(name = "company_type", nullable = false)
    String companyType;

    @Column(name = "company_gst")
    String gstNumber;

    @Column(name = "company_pan", nullable = false)
    String panCardNumber;
}

But I am getting below error
    2024-11-26 01:28:11.399 ERROR 97993 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'user_id' cannot be null
    2024-11-26 01:28:11.608 ERROR 97993 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.f.c.exception.CustomExceptionHandler   : exception occurred: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

I am getting this error for CompanyInformation entity and not for Address entity even though I have defined them as same.
I'm new to Spring. What can I try next?

There's a constraint violation as the error message says.  You have defined some values as non-nullable (like user_id) but they are null at the time of saving the entity (so you need to fix that before saving it to the db).  You need to provide more code on how you are invoking the same (i.e. [edit] the question and add a [mre] to it)

It looks like you need to check your database constraints. If you have set user_id as not null for table "company_info".
Also, I am not sure what your actual requirement of the project is but having onetoone join with user_id in company_info & address table is not making sense to me. Why any company will have only one user? May it should be onetomany or manytomany depending upon your requirement.
My suggestion will be to check what should be your db design and correct the table joining in backend accrodingly.
Let me know if this helps or if you have further question.
Here's a way to achieve what you are looking for.
Add below lines in your User entity.
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
@ToString.Exclude
Address address;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
@ToString.Exclude
CompanyInformation companyInformation;

Add this to your CompanyInformation entity
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "companyInformation")
User user;

Similar for Address entity
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
User user;


Thanks for your reply. Actually my design is such that there will be only one company and one user. So if I want to save company Id and address Id both at user level how can I achieve that?

Check my edited answer.
